# python list comprehension does not work with list.extend

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of glob patterns. For each glob pattern, I get the matching file list, and I want to combine all the file lists with list comprehension to be **one flattened list**:

```
patterns = [
    "some_pattern1",
    "some_pattern2"
]
all_files = []
all_files.extend(glob.glob(pattern)) for pattern in patterns
```

However this gives me a syntax error, I can do the list merge with:

```
for pattern in patterns:
    all_files.extend(glob.glob(pattern))
```

I think those two syntax are equivalent. Why the list comprehension doesn't work with extend?

For exmaple, consider `some_pattern1` matches two files `[1.txt, 2.txt]`; `some_patter2` matches `[3.txt, 4.txt]`, I'm looking for a way to combine the two lists to be: `[1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt, 4.txt]`

Comment: I think you should use `all_files.extend([glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in patterns])`.

Comment: Could you please give us an example of what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @YangHanlin sorry didn't make myself clear, I wanted to have a flattened list which is a result of the combined list. Your answer gives me (in the updated example: `[[[1.txt,2.txt],[3.txt,4.txt]]]`)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with the extend method.

Your syntax is wrong. You should write it this way:-

```
patterns = [
    "some_pattern1",
    "some_pattern2"
]
all_files = []
all_files.extend([glob.glob(pattern) for pattern in patterns])
```

It will return output like this:-

```
[['1.txt', '2.txt'], ['3.txt', '4.txt']]
```

Add this to the code:

```
sum(all_files, [])
```

Now the output will be like this:-

```
['1.txt', '2.txt', '3.txt', '4.txt']
```

Comment: Never use `sum` for list concatenation. Doing so takes quadratic time.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply invalid syntax,
`all_files.extend(glob.glob(pattern)) for pattern in patterns` 
looks like the [syntax for list comprehension](http://This%20is%20simply%20invalid%20syntax,%20%60all_files.extend(glob.glob(pattern))%20for%20pattern%20in%20patterns%20%60%20is%20the%20syntax%20for%20list%20comprehension,%20which%20you're%20not%20trying%20to%20perform), which you're not trying to perform here.